# sublime text3 auto complete issue

Tags: sublimetext3

I use Sublime Text3 under Linux Mint 17.3 and I have a problem with the auto complete pop-up menu. For each key I press in order to complete the command, the menu **pops up for just a tiny fraction of time.**

I added to the *Preferences-> Settings - User* each one from both lines below,

```
"auto_complete": true
```

and

```
"auto_complete_selector": "source, text"
```

but none solved the problem.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: So, the autocomplete menu is showed but disappears immediately, is that the problem you are describing?

Comment: @sergioFC That's right.

Comment: I am also using ST3 under Linux Mint 17.3 and I have never had that problem. Maybe this is caused by some setting, plugin or package you have recently changed or installed?

Comment: @sergioFC I'm afraid that you are right, so I guess that I have to reinstall